# Set docusign envelope TTL?

Tags: docusignapi

How can I set the TTL on an envelope to be signed by Captive recipients?

I've googled `docusign api ttl` and searched StackOverflow. Surprisingly I see references that Docusign can say an envelope has expired, but I've not seen how to set the expiry time for an envelope.

In my testing, I generated a bunch of envelopes that I sent to myself, that I didn't sign. Docusign keeps sending reminders about them. Now it's been 2 days since the envelopes were generated. I don't want the clients receiving emails about it so long after they were supposed to sign.

My intention is they will be re-directed from my web-app to Docusign, they sign, then they come back to my app.
If they don't sign by the end of the day (I'll set the TTL dynamically) then the envelope and it's URL must expire and they must not keep getting emails about it. If they want to sign after that, they must login to my web-app, then ask to sign again, and a new envelope will be generated for them, and they'll be redirected to it.

How can I set the TTL for the envelope?

---

EDIT:

I just found this:
[Embedded Signing api docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571263/embedded-signing-api-docusign/17577806#17577806)

The unrelated, but relevant answer claims that captive recipient URLs have a TTL of 5 minutes.
So a 5 min expiry for the envelope URL is fine, but I don't want the customer getting emails from docusign about it constantly for 2 days afterwards. I want the whole envelope/contract to expire within a short time. As above.

---

EDIT 2

I'm using the params mentioned by CodingDawg to good effect,

However my signer still gets emails from Docusign to say that they've viewed the envelope etc. It may be a little confusing to them.

I've moved this question to a separate SO question:
[Suppress emails to embedded signers (captive recipients) or at least add text to the unwanted emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485066/suppress-emails-to-embedded-signers-captive-recipients-or-at-least-add-text-to)

Comment: Please post EDIT2 as a new question so that it can be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the notification property in your [Envelope:Create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) api call to set the TTL for an evelope.

Here is a sample Request. You can see the definition of the following properties [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definitions--notification) (After clicking the link expand the notification accordian)

```
"notification": {
   "expirations": {
     "expireAfter": 2,
     "expireEnabled": true,
     "expireWarn": 2
   },
   "reminders": {
     "reminderDelay": 2,
     "reminderEnabled": false,
     "reminderFrequency": 2
   },
 "useAccountDefaults": false
}
```

Comment: Please see Edit 2?

Comment: @Josh Please post it as a new question rather than a Edit as it seems like a slightly different topic

Comment: Signer can manage their email notifications using this page. Sender cannot control these. https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-manage-notifications