# Suppress emails to embedded signers (captive recipients) or at least add text to the unwanted emails?

Tags: docusignapi

I generate an envelope for the customer to sign as a embedded (captive recipient) so they do not receive an email, instead I redirect them to the new envelope from my app, the intention is that they come back, in a seamless experience.

However what's happening is when they visit the URL, Docusign sends them an unwanted email. So for example if their name is Josh, they will receive an email from Docusign, with
Subject: "Josh viewed Please sign contract X"
Body: Title: "Josh viewed Please sign contract X"
Body: Description: At (time) Josh opened and viewed your documents, Contract X.pdf

This is not a good customer experience. Josh receives a lame email talking about him in the 3rd person. The link in the email requires the customer to register with Docusign which is just a hassle for them, it adds no value whatsoever. They can view the contract within my web-app.

**Preferred question**
How can I suppress as many emails as possible from Docusign to the customer, using the API? I've examined the [API docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) but didn't find anything there about suppressing emails for embedded stuff.

Apparently it can be done via the classic preferences. But I always prefer to override these things in code. Is it possible to suppress the emails with options in the API?

[image: Classic prefs suppressing emails to embedded recipients]

**Alternative question**
I tried adding the following options to the create envelope request, to at least embed an explanation for the customer, to say what the unwanted Docusign emails are about. But only text subject2 appeared. But not in a good way.
I got am email with the subject: "Josh viewed Test subject2"
No custom body appeared un the unwanted email.

`recipientEmailNotification: {
   emailBody: 'Test body',
   emailSubject: 'Test subject'
  },
  emailBody: 'Test body2',
  emailSubject: 'Test subject 2',`

**EDIT:**

Thanks CodingDawg, you've cleared things up for me quite a bit.

You've got a good point there, I may have confusing emails, because my admin email address is the same email address as my first recipient (I realize now it's a bad idea for testing, I'll use a different email address)

**EDIT 2**

I see now there are email settings in admin preferences, and also in user preferences. Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused between Sender and Recipient emails.

- After an envelope is sent to an embedded recipient the recipient does not get any emails immediately.
- After the Sending App generates a signing link and redirects to the recipient , **Sender**(not recipient) gets an email saying the "Recipient viewed envelope"

  - The "Recipient Viewed envelope" email can be suppressed in the senders account preferences. See info for NDSE [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-manage-notifications) , CDSE [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-user-guide-account-preferences-manage-email-notification)
- After the Embedded Recipient signs the envelope, the recipient will receive an "Envelope is completed" email

  - The "Envelope completed" email can be prevented from sending to the recipient by selecting the "Suppress emails to Embedded Signers" checkbox in the sender's account preferences. Please note that this is an Account wide setting and cannot be done at per envelope level. More info [here](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/signing-settings.htm)

---

**recipientEmailNotification**

The recipientEmailNotification property that you have specified in your request is invalid. Here is a sample json for [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) api to set email body/subject at recipient level.

In the following example,

- "*recipient one*" will receive an email with subject "*This is recipient one subject*".
- "*recipient two*"  will receive an email with subject "*Email Subject to all recipients*"

JSON

```
 {
   "status": "sent",
   "emailSubject": "Email Subject to all recipients",
   "emailBlurb": "Email body to all recipients",
   "recipients": {
     "signers": [
       {
         "recipientId": 1,
         "email": "recipient1@foobar.com",
         "name": "recipient one",
         "emailNotification": {
           "emailSubject": "This is recipient one subject",
           "emailBody": "This is recipient one email body"
         }
       },
       {
         "recipientId": 2,
         "email": "recipient2@foobar.com",
         "name": "recipient two"
       }
     ]
   },
   "documents": [
     {
       "documentId": 1,
       "fileExtension": "txt",
       "name": "Test Document",
      "documentBase64": "VGVzdCBEb2N1bWVudA=="
     }
   ],
   "emailBody": "envelope level email Body"
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome example JSON and your answer. I didn't find the options you mentioned at first, but then found it and updated my edit. I'll revert after I've tried your JSON schema.